C++ problem when deleting an element from vector of pointers
I'll try to put it as simply as possible. Note I've looked for hours on here for answers and every wiki page too and banged my head against this for days.
The project is a single line calculator the specific problematic code part is:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> toProcess = { "5","*","(","5","+","5",")"};
    vector<int> operatorPositions = { 1,2,4,6};
    vector<int*> operatorOrder;
    for (int i = 0; i < operatorPositions.size(); i++)
    {
        operatorOrder.push_back(&operatorPositions.at(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < operatorPositions.size(); i++)
    {
        if (toProcess.at(operatorPositions.at(i)) == "(" || toProcess.at(operatorPositions.at(i)) == ")")
        {
            int storedPosition = operatorPositions.at(i);

            for (int j = i + 1; j < operatorPositions.size(); j++)
            {
                operatorPositions.at(j)--;
            }

            operatorOrder.erase(operatorOrder.begin() + i);
            operatorPositions.erase(operatorPositions.begin() + i);

            toProcess.erase(toProcess.begin() + storedPosition);
        }
    }

    cout << "Operator Positions: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < operatorPositions.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << operatorPositions.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Operator Order: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < operatorOrder.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << *operatorOrder.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "toProcess: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < toProcess.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << toProcess.at(i) << " ";
    }
}

Expected Result:
operatorPositions = {1, 3}
operator Order should mach operatorPositions
toProcess = {"5", "*", "5", "+", "5"}
The printed out operatorPositions and operatorOrder should be the exact same and the number should correspond to the operator position in the toProcess vector. But without the parenthesis and then parenthesis positions missing from operatorOrder and operatorPositions.
Full code can be viewed here: https://github.com/SpoonWasAlreadyTaken/Single-Line-Calculator
at this moment operatorPositions and operatorOrder are the same. operatorPositions is an int vector and operatorOrder is a int pointer vector.
toProcess is a string vector that is the input parsed between operators and numbers. would look something like:
Input: 5*(5+5)
toProcess: 5,*,(,5,+,5,)
operatorPositions: 1,2,4,6
To make parenthesis count for higher priority in order of operations I need to delete an element from a vector of ints that has operator positions and an element from a vector of pointers to the previous vectors elements.
But in doing so it comes out weird having wrong elements deleted or having more elements or less.
The code piece can be found at comment //bracket removal.
Can be reproduced by using 5*(5+5)
(5+5)*5 works fine
I know it's not the best code but I'm trying to learn.
Iv since realized a better way to do it but I still want to learn and know what's wrong there.
Thank you

When you erase elements of the vector you iterate over, the index variable i will no longer be correct. I suggest you step through the loop with a debugger tro see what happens. And to use a pencil and paper to try and figure out how to solve the problem.

OK can't follow what you are trying to do exactly but here's a couple of points (1) Learn to use a debugger, when the debugger tells you that your code has done something different from what you expect you have your bug. (2) When you delete something from your vectors you also increment i, that means you are skipping elements in your vectors. If you delete, don't increment i.

Maybe you shouldn't be using std::vector, looks like you have more like a queue or stack?

so far it hasnt skipped over any elements, that hasnt been the problem. The problem is if I delete an element from both the Order vector and Position vector something strange happens. If I only delete from Order it works fine but then it breaks later on in the code.

I have used a debugger and my own debug code which wasnt included in the example. And I know exactly what the problem is but not how to solve it or what is even causing it.

yes a queue would be preferable but I didnt know of their existance when I started coding this as part of learning.

I can clearly see its nots.
operatorPositions and operatorORder should mach.
this outputs:
operatorPositoons: 1, 3
operatorOrder: 1, 5

@Spoon -- Side note -- why are you using this rather unorthodox way of calculating an expression?  There is the shunting yard algorthm, as well as using the traditional method using an operand/operator stack.  The issue with doing this approach you've come up with may not show up with your current toy example, but as soon as the expressions get even a little bit more complex, you will be tearing your hair out trying to adjust your code to handle those expressions correctly.

@PaulMcKenzie the simple answer to that is I simply wasn't aware of those things. Its just me trying to learn cpp. Picking up after not doing anything in it for nearly 5 years.
I hadn't looked anything up to do a single line calculator. Well I had but only to find that I couldnt find anything at  quick glance.
Again simply a learning experience.

@Spoon Well, it's just to warn you.  It is sort of well-known that programs that attempt to do ad-hoc expression evaluations will almost never work when the expression becomes "different" or even slightly more complex than expected.  What winds up happening is that the coder has to start again from scratch (or add copious "duct tape", making the program almost impossible to maintain), just to accommodate the new expression they are having trouble with.  To counteract this, you would use formal ways, such as the shunting yard that was mentioned, or some sort of grammar/expression parser, etc.

@PaulMcKenzie I learned a similar lesson, while not having to start from scratch I did have to add a not so insignificant amount of code to get parenthesis working well working isnt really the right term but still.
In the future I will try a more formal method but as I mentioned of my first cursory search I hadn't found anything. But what you referenced to will help. (:

When you erase elements from operatorPositions and operatorOrder, the pointers you have in operatorOrder will be "one-off". Looking at the actual content:



address offset of elementin operatorPositions
operatorPositions(value)
operatorOrder(value)




0x00
1
0x00


0x08
2
0x08


0x10
4
0x10


0x18
6
0x18



The first one you will erase is the operatorPositions element carrying the value 2. After you've erased that, and the pointer pointing at it, you'll have:



address offset of elementin operatorPositions
operatorPositions(value)
operatorOrder(value)




0x00
1
0x00


0x08
4
0x10


0x10
6
0x18



Note how the addresses of the elements in operatorPositions shifted down and how the pointers in operatorOrder now point to the wrong elements and that the last one points to an element that no longer exists.
You need to make them point at the previous element to match.
You are also increasing i even when you erase. Should two operators of interest be adjacent in toProcess, you'd miss the second one. Only increase i when you not erase elements.
Example:
for (size_t i = 0; i < operatorPositions.size();) {
    auto it = toProcess.begin() + operatorPositions[i];

    if (*it == "(" || *it == ")") {            
        toProcess.erase(it);

        operatorOrder.erase(operatorOrder.begin() + i);
        for (size_t j = i; j < operatorOrder.size(); j++) {
            operatorOrder.at(j)--;     // adjust the pointers too
        }

        operatorPositions.erase(operatorPositions.begin() + i);
        for (size_t j = i; j < operatorPositions.size(); j++) {
            operatorPositions.at(j)--;
        }
    } else {
        ++i;                 // only increase i if no erasing has been done
    }
}

Demo

thank you very much for the explanation.

@Spoon You're welcome! Glad it helped!

I think you want this:
auto itorPos = operatorPositions.begin();
auto itorOrder = operatorOrder.begin();

while (itorPos != operatorPositions.end())
{
    if (toProcess.at(*itorPos) == "(" || toProcess.at(*itorPos) == ")")
    {
        int storedPosition = *itorPos;

        for (auto itor2 = itorPos+1; itor2 != operatorPositions.end(); itor2++)
        {
            (*itor2)--;
        }
        
        itorOrder = operatorOrder.erase(itorOrder);
        itorPos = operatorPositions.erase(itorPos);

        toProcess.erase(toProcess.begin() + storedPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        itorOrder++;
        itorPos++;
    }
}

The above changes are basically this:

Use an iterator instead of an index variable
Use a while loop instead of a for loop
When erasing, the erase method will return an updated iterator that references the next item in the collection
When not erasing, we manually increment the iterators ourselves.


this approach doesn't function still. And breaks in the same way. When deleting from operatorOrder and operatorPositions it deletes weird, not the right elements. When deleting only from one it does delete the right elements but then it only deletes from it.

Reason for you are not getting expected output is that (for the given input) operatorOrder is holding addresses of operatorPositions vector elements which were stored in the operatorPositions vector after the element which was erased. Those addresses no more valid after erase.
From vector/erase [emphasis added]:

Iterators (including the end() iterator) and references to the elements at or after the point of the erase are invalidated.

May, you should rewrite the operatorOrder, after erasing element in operatorPositions, from the point of erase to the end or clear and rewrite whole operatorOrder.
In for loop, remove this statement:
        operatorOrder.erase(operatorOrder.begin() + i);

and add below piece of code after statement operatorPositions.erase(operatorPositions.begin() + i);, i.e. after erasing an element in operatorPositions vector:
        operatorOrder.clear();

        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < operatorPositions.size(); x++)
        {
            operatorOrder.push_back(&operatorPositions.at(x));
        }

and you will get expected output:
Operator Positions: 1 3 
Operator Order: 1 3 
toProcess: 5 * 5 + 5 


thank you very much for the explanation.
